# Chrome continuously showing add to home screen bar

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I enabled pwa on my website and now chrome is showing `add to home screen` prompt and it is ok. Now i added my site to home screen through prompt and reloaded my website but chrome is still showing `add to home screen` even i added to my home screen. Ideally chrome should not show up `add to home screen` prompt if user added to his home screen. I think i am missing something on coding side.

Comment: Mobile or desktop?

Comment: Are you running incognito mode or do you have any extensions that clear out your browsers cache? If so, the browser will of course not remember that you may have added it.

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding, It is happening in mobile. cache is not being cleared because it is showing cached pages in offline mode.

Comment: On Android?  After you close the browser, then look at applications (not home screen) do you see the icon for your PWA?  - Also is the issue reproducible on someone else's phone?

Comment: Hey Man, I did test the feature on some one else android phone and every thing working fine as i expected and i can't reproduce issue. I think some thing wrong with my android phone. You can also test here is the link https://satyagrah.scroll.in. I think you understood the issue. can you please explain issue if you understood? Thanks

Comment: I just have very wild guesses. 1. Some sort of security setting on your phone is preventing the webAPK from being installted fully? 2. You have an older version of OS or chrome?

Comment: A2HS fine on my Pixel 2 XL - just asking to install once. One other trick I sometimes do to check install. After the chrome install, open the website in Firefox. If installed well (with chrome), you will see an Android Robot icon in the firefox address bar. Clicking on that will open the standalone chrome install.

Comment: If you are running Chrome 69 beta, I think there is currently a bug that prompts for install when it shouldn't.